# JBehave - large number of steps in a scenario, due to preconditions and pre-steps

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, bdd, jbehave

I'm having a scenario which consists of around 500 steps.

About 490 steps out of the it are preconditions and steps that needs to be done, in order to come to a state where the actual acceptance (last 10 steps) can be done.

Is it really bad to have a large number of steps inside a single scenario.
Is there a better approach where I can keep the original scenario bit clean and separate the preconditions.

Comment: Welcome to SQA. Having so many steps as preconditions seems like a nightmare to me. It depends on a situation, but think about how it can be simplified, because I assume that maintenance of such a scenario is time-consuming and requires so much past knowledge that e.g. new members of the team might not have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out a tailor made solution for these kind of situations, from JBehave documentation.

"To help the user better manager more complex scenarios, JBehave allow the specification of entire stories as a pre-requisite for another story or scenario."

https://jbehave.org/reference/latest/given-stories.html

Answer (score 1):

https://cucumber.io/docs/bdd/better-gherkin/

Even though the question is with JBehave, I think cucumber provides better documentation and will help you understand Gherkins better.

To summaries:

> Your scenarios should describe the intended behaviour of the system,
>   not the implementation. In other words, it should describe what, not
>   how.

so instead of :

```
open browser
provide password
provide username
click login
user logins
he clicks the first item
```

use:

```
user logins to portal
Adds item to cart
Checkouts and makes the payment
```

The actual implementation is hidden in the step definition. `The user logins to portal` actually reuses the functions to enter password ,click login etc  , in the step definition.

Hide the implementation details in step definition and in feature file use only the process.

In your case add step like ,

```
user completes the prerequeiste tasks
```

add use it to wrap the actual 490 steps inside step-definition:

**Running step before each story:**

If you want to run this step before each story, then use **before** (if using jbehave syntax)

else use **Background** (If using Gherkin syntax)

Read more at:

https://jbehave.org/reference/latest/story-syntax.html

https://www.coveros.com/writing-effective-cucumber-tests/

Comment: It's not easy to implement more high level steps like you've mentioned, when the low level steps are heavily parametrized (etc : tabular parameters).